# Type inference on Typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript, types, interface, structure, inference

If we have this structure on typescript:

```
type A = {
  v: number | string[]
}

interface B {
  a: A;
}

class C implements B {
  a = {
    v: 3 // inference only with type number, string[] is lost
  } 
}

c = new C();
c.a.v = ['hello']; // not working, needs a: A on class C


// Working class must be:

class C implements B {
  a: A = {
    v: 3
  } 
}
```

Does anybody know if there's a workaround to avoid setting de type on "a" on each class?

Comment: You're running into [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and scads of linked issues.  I'm not sure what workaround you would accept that's any better than an explicit type annotation when the compiler infers a narrower type than what you want.  Anything I can think of would be way worse.

Comment: I think it would be better infering types from definitions (types or interfaces) if any. If no types are present then infer them from values. If a subset of original definitions are needed to limit the scope, then that should be specified and not the type again if the original definition matches what you want.

Comment: Sure, I think I understand the behavior you want, but TypeScript does not currently work that way and the linked issue above talks about it.  Note that there is likely real world code that relies on the current behavior which is also arguably correct, so even if people agree in principle on the change it might not be worth breaking others.   I'm trying to figure out what constitutes an answer you'd accept, since the question is asking for a workaround, not an explanation of the current TS behavior.

Comment: "Workaround" as if any other knew a "magic" way typescript could infer that way. Anyway, I thankfully accept your answer.